# Unless Clause Leaving Blank Space in Collection Page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I asked about including a where clause in the collections page the other day but decided to scrap going that route. I'm now just using `unless` logic in the page. This route has worked except for one tiny flaw. When I include the `unless` clause in the collection.liquid page, the grid still leaves an empty space where the product that's being ignored would normally sit, and also including it in the count. How can I get this space to go away and how can I get it to not include it in the product count? It seems like the unless clause is just keeping it from appearing, not truly excluding it.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="{% if settings.show_collection_sidebar %}desktop-10{% else 
%}desktop-12{% endif %} tablet-6 mobile-3" id="bside">

    <div id="product-loop">
        {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% unless product.title contains "Sampler" %}
            <div class="product {% if settings.products_per_row  == '3' 
            %}desktop-4{% cycle ' first', '', ' last' %}{% elsif 
            settings.products_per_row == '4' %}desktop-3{% cycle ' first', 
            '', '', ' last' %}{% endif %} tablet-half mobile-half" id="prod-
            {{ product.id }}" data-alpha="{{ product.title }}" data-price="
            {{ product.price }}">
                {% include 'product-listing' %}
            </div>
        {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried moving around where the unless code is, outside the for loop, outside the product loop, but nothing has worked.

Thanks,
RDV

Comment: Just add "forloop.index" somewhere inside "unless" to see if the condition is working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Would it be:
`{% unless forloop.index contains "Sampler" %}` ?

Comment: I should have been clear. Try this `{% unless product.title contains "Sampler" %}<script>console.log({{forloop.index}})</script> ....`

Open up your browser's console and see if the `unless` condition is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written *should* be working - I would check your product-listing snippet for anything referencing `forloop.index`, since the index is a variable that will be incremented even if you're not doing anything on that iteration.

For cleanliness in the liquid code, I usually use the `continue` statement so that I'm not wrapping potentially huge blocks of code with liquid tags - I find that it gets hard enough to keep track of all the openings/closings in liquid if I'm doing moderately complex stuff otherwise.  So with this example, instead of using `unless` you could consider `{% if product.title contains 'Sampler' %}{% continue %}{% endif %}`

But all of this is ignoring the most powerful tool that we have at our disposal - making sure the collection only contains the right products in the first place!

I'm assuming that you're looking at your "All Products" collection with this code. By default, there's an invisible collection in your store called "All" that, true to its name, contains every product visible in the online store.  However, you can override this by making your own collection named 'All' (specifically, with a handle of 'all' - the actual title doesn't matter as long as this is the handle).  If you want "All" to mean "Everything that's not a sampler", just make a "Smart Collection" with the condition "Product title DOES NOT CONTAIN 'Sample'" - and voilà! There's nothing to skip and the total count will always be correct!

Comment: And if you're *not* looking at the 'All products' collection with the code above, I strongly recommend updating your rules for the collection to simply exclude the offending products ;)

Comment: One challenge is that there are three samplers. One is a generic one, the other two belong to collections because they are samplers for those collections. I am currently working on the collection versions, the non-collection one was simple since it's contained in its own section.

Comment: @RedDeadVolvo - Sorry for the delayed response, I don't remember to check StackOverflow very often when things get busy.  If you're already looking through collections, what's stopping you from having a collection that only has the products that you care about so that the results are pre-filtered?